# Can I remove NuGet.exe from the Solution folder

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 after upgrading from 2015. The problem I am having is when calling MSBuild from the command line, older projects which have a NuGet.exe within the .nuget folder inside the project/solution directory will fail to build because they've got an old version of the exe.

Can I delete the NuGet.exe from .nuget folders, remove references to it in the csproj files, and use one central NuGet.exe from this point on?

Is this the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that `.nuget\NuGet.targets` and `.nuget\NuGet.exe` thing is from Visual Studio 2013 and earlier. Not only is it causing you problems now, but every build and restore from in Visual Studio 2015 and later has been slower because these projects are using this old "integration". (NuGet is probably restoring in VS, and then when the build happens, the restore via nuget.exe in NuGet.targets is running, doing a second restore check)

The NuGet team have some docs, with instructions in the "Migrate to automatic package restore (Visual Studio)" section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrate-to-automatic-package-restore-visual-studio